# Custom Dialog crashes?

Tags: android, android-dialog

i have a imagebutton in a layout. i want to use this as a launcher of a custom dialog. but when i click it the program crashes. code im using is below:

```
ImageButton bt = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.print_button);

    bt.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Dialog dialog = new Dialog(Details.this);
            dialog.setContentView(R.layout.sharepopup);
            dialog.setTitle("");
            dialog.setCancelable(true);
            dialog.show();
          }
    }
```

whats wrong with that? thanks in advance.

Comment: I tried your code using just using my layout in dialog.setContentView its working not a problem check your layout or put log trace.

Comment: thanks guys. when i put getparent() as a parameter of dialog constructor...it runs well.

Answer (score 0):

```
LayoutInflater newProject = LayoutInflater.from(Details.this);
View projectView =newProject.inflate(R.layout.sharepopup, null);

Dialog dialog= new Dialog(Details.this);
dialog.setContentView(projectView);
....
```

try this...

Comment: its still not working .....but i LogCat it and noticed that the dialog.show() is crashing

Comment: try to initialize the dialog in main activity and use it in onClick listener , instead initialize it in onclick listener